# Android and sqlite update

Tags: android, sqlite

I currently have a working sqlite database with one table that is functioning with my application,

but I wanted to add a couple more columns, I looked this up and it looks like it requires an alter-table, executed onUpgrade,

- does this mean I have to upgrade the sqlite database completely in
  order to just add the two columns I need?
- Is this the only way to tweak the table?
- If I have a typo or anything, I have to upgrade?

I am fairly new to sqlite and general dbms, so forgive my ignorance

Comment: Some terminlogy here: "upgrade" your database usually means to install a newer version of SQLite, which isn't what you want or need to do in this case.  Just bite the bullet do the `ALTER TABLE`, it's not so bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is already released and customers are using it, then you'll want to use the `onUpgrade` method to keep their data and just upgrade their local databases to the new schema by running `ALTER TABLE` commands, etc.

If customers don't have your app yet, then you can just delete it from your simulator or test device.  Then, just modify the `onCreate` method to have the right columns from the start.  When you start up your app, it should create the database with your desired schema.

Comment: I don't think anyone has installed it yet > >
I'll check, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQLiteOpenHelper class has public procedure for creating app's DB with parameters DBname and DBversion.

If DBVersion changed (is other than current DB version on device) method onUpgrade called. In method onUpgrade you have to call commands for changing table structure.

```
public class dbSQLadapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "peredovik";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 23;

    public dbSQLadapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```